# Left-align entire document

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I'd like to left align my entire document (latex default seems to be center justified). Is there a simple way to do this?

I'm trying to use

```
\begin{flushleft}
...
\end{flushleft}
```

but really don't want to have to do that on a paragraph by paragraph basis (and when I try to simply add that to the start and end of my document I get an error.

Answer (score 21):

Just use:

```
\raggedright
```

right after `\begin{document}`

The `flushleft` environment effectively sets text in a ragged right list environment.  It is defined as:

```
\def\flushleft{\trivlist \raggedright\item\relax} 
\def\endflushleft{\endtrivlist}
```

The `\raggedright` command does the actual work:

```
\def\raggedright{%
   \let\\\@centercr\@rightskip\@flushglue \rightskip\@rightskip
   \leftskip\z@skip
   \parindent\z@}
```

Setting text this way will lead to some ugly looking lines. The [`ragged2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ragged2e) package provides the `\RaggedRight` command (and corresponding) `FlushLeft` environment that solves some of these problems.  I would recommend using it instead of just `\raggedright`.

To see the differences between `\raggedright` and `\RaggedRight` here's a small sample document:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyphenat}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\textbf{raggedright with no hyphenation}\par
\raggedright
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.4\textwidth}
\textbf{RaggedRight with hyphenation}\par
\RaggedRight
\blindtext
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Both `\raggedright` and `\RaggedRight` set the paragraph indent to zero.  With `ragged2e` this is controllable with the length `\RaggedRightParindent` which can be set to equal the regular `\parindent` in the following way:

```
\setlength{\RaggedRightParindent}{\parindent}
```

To do this with regular `\raggedright` you could do the following:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\newlength{\rrindent}
\setlength{\rrindent}{\parindent}
\apptocmd{\raggedright}{\setlength{\parindent}{\rrindent}}{}{}
```

Comment: Can the same result be achieved by completely disabling hyphenation?

Comment: @Raphink same result as what? Disabling hyphenation with justified text will just lead to ugly interword spacing, but still justified,  not ragged right text. Turning off hyphenation with `\RaggedRight` will get you the same as `\raggedright`.

Comment: You broke the paragraph indent.

Comment: @PavelŠimerda Yes, both versions reset the `\parindent` to zero. I've added some comments on how to change them back.

Comment: Alan Munn suggestion is one of the good one...

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `\raggedright` to have a flush left typesetting:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% dummy text
\raggedright% flush left alignment
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]% 10 paragraphs of summy text
\end{document}​​​​​​​​​​​
```

[image: Ragged-right aligned document]

Comment: You broke the paragraph indent.